# getting an issue http/ 1.1 500 internal server error while opening asp.net project in vs 2003

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

Getting this issue while opening asp.net 1.1 project in vs 2003..

[image: this is the exact error message]

I tried [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/822319) solution, but didnt helped..

and [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/899533.aspx?+HTTP+1+1+500+Internal+Server+Error+Please+someone+help+I+am+new+to+this+all+) one.

Answer (score 0):

A few things come to mind.  1, in the 1.1 days, I think you needed to have IIS installed.  Are you on a machine with IIS installed.. and if so.. IIS 6?  If not, I'm not sure how well you'll be able to run the project.

2, If the answer to question 1 is yes, look at your Windows Event Viewer, 500 level errors should be captured there, and hopefully will give you some clues - if it's a security issue, configuration problem, etc.

3, you can always attempt to upgrade the project and run it in a newer version of visual studio.. you are trying to use a project that is 12+ years old after all..

Comment: i have iis installed its 8.0.. as per 12+ years old.. i have this project as a service for some other projects.. so i need to compile it with same 1.1 version.